# Get current element on(keyup) and pass as argument to another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assume my webpage has the following dynamically generated textbox elements with class='mytxt'.

```
<input type="text" class="mytxt" />
<input type="text" class="mytxt" />
<input type="text" class="mytxt" />
```

How do I get current textbox element user is typing on and pass it to another function as argument. Something like:

```
 $("body").on("keyup", ".mytxt" ,function(element) {
    // where element is current textbox element user is typing on
    someFunction(element);
});
```

I know it is possible to have onkeyup in html and pass 'this' as argument as shown below, but this isn't an option for me since I don't have access to the code that dynamically generates the textbox elements.

```
<input type="text" class="mytxt" onkeyup="someFunction(this);"/>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The delegate event will pass a variable which is an event. We can get the element from `event.target`

[See MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)

```
$("body").on("keyup", ".mytxt" ,function(event) {
    var element = event.target;
    someFunction(element);
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Hikarunomemory. This is exactly what I was looking for.